# RegEx match all tags text within

Tags: regex

I’m fighting with some regular expressions to identify the inline tags within some YML files I do frequently receive.

I do need to identify with a Regex Expression the following type of tags:

```
<p class='link-pdf'>
</li>
<a id = 'pdf' href='#' target='_blank' class= 'pdf' onclick='location.href=\"/pdf/help/%{language}/download.pdf\"'>
```

I tried many regex's... but none of them worked..

¿could somebody help me?

Comment: Can you post those tried regexes?

Comment: I've tried several ones, from <\w+> to <a href=\"%{\W+}\">   or %\{[^\{]+\}    but as I'm not expert on the field I didnt post it before...

Comment: So are you looking to extract just the <a> tags? Are you expecting them to be properly formed? ( eg <a blahblah>text</a> ) Would you ever expect self closing tags (like <a blahblah />)

Comment: I do not mind if they are properly formed or not as I want to identify them so as to edit the text between them, as in your example (eg <a blahblah>text</a>) and yes, I want closing tags also to be included in the identification. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on your last comment.

A regex which captures all the tags of the form text might look like:

```
<a[^>]*>(.(?!</a>))*.?</a>
```

this breaks down as

- `<a[^>]*>` = `<a` followed by any number of characters that are NOT a `>` and then a `>`
- `(.(?!</a>))*` = Any character NOT followed by `</a>`, repeated any number of times (could be 0)
- `.?` = Any character (optional)
- `</a>` = Finally the closing tag.

If you want the interior of the tag to be a capturing group then its

```
<a[^>]*>((?:.(?!</a>))*.?)</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your invaluable help.  It worked perfectly and solved all my doubts of these past weeks.  Hope you have a good day ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I understand you want to match the inside of `<a>` tags, no matter how messed up the attributes are :

```
(<\s*a\s*[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<\s*/\s*a[^>]*>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The second capture group will contain the text.